# specifying _fields_ with init or altering after initialization

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am in a situation where I have many structs which represent the same idea but use different data types. For example:

```
// mylib.c 

typedef struct DblArr DblArr;
typedef struct IntArr IntArr;

struct DblArr {
    int length;
    double *data
};

struct IntArr {
    int length;
    int *data
};

double dblsum(*DblArr) {
    double sum = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i< Arr->length; i++) {
        sum = sum + Arr->data[i];
    }
    
    return sum;
}

int intsum(*IntArr) {
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i< Arr->length; i++) {
        sum = sum + Arr->data[i];
    }
    
    return sum;
}
```

If possible, I would like to use ctypes to encapsulate these structures in a single class to then pass to my functions in `libmylib.so`. I tried doing something like this:

```
from ctypes import *

class Arr(Structure):
    def __init__(self, dtype, length, data):
        self.dtype = dtype
        self.length = length
        
        arr_type = dtype * length
        arr_instance = arr_type(*data)
        self.data = arr_instance
        
        self._fields_ = [("length", c_int), ("data", POINTER(dtype))]
```

but python crashes when I initialize a variable. Does anyone have any suggestions or know if this is not possible?

Comment: Why don't you use one struct type with a union for the data? You'd need a type enumeration in the struct so that your Python code could cast the data to the correct type. Or maybe Python understands C unions?

Comment: Does this help: http://www.cdotson.com/2015/05/c-style-unions-and-python/

Comment: From *C* perspective, unions are what you're looking for. In *Python* you could define *ctypes.Structure* descendants dynamically (in functions).